# Formula Math Excel

Tags: math, excel-formula, statistics

I have to solve a problem:
In the cell of the column 'PMi(TGRneto(N)cedido)' I have to put this formula:

=IF(J3="0";0;IF(J3="-";"-";IF(J3="calcolo";IF(ROW(L3)<4;"-";IF(ISNUMBER(Input!$C$13);LOOKUP(2;1/($L2:L$3<>"-");$L2:L$3)*(1+Input!$C$13)^((H3-H3)/365);"")))))

but, in the case that there is written 'calcolo' in the column 'Appoggio', I have to put this formula that considers the date rate difference:

K7 :
=IF(J7="0";0;IF(J7="-";"-";IF(J7="calcolo";IF(ROW(L7)<4;"-";IF(ISNUMBER(Input!$C$13);LOOKUP(2;1/($L$3:L6<>"-");$L$3:L6)*(1+Input!$C$13)^((I7-H3)/365);"")))))

K8 :
=IF(J8="0";0;IF(J8="-";"-";IF(J8="calcolo";IF(ROW(L8)<4;"-";IF(ISNUMBER(Input!$C$13);LOOKUP(2;1/($L$3:L7<>"-");$L$3:L7)*(1+Input!$C$13)^((I8-I7)/365);"")))))

I put the images

K3
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fgu1j.png)

K7
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpt2R.png)

K8
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liwWS.png)

Could u please do the formula correct? I want the formula starts from K3 in a massive way.

Thanks

Correct results done